# How can I convert base 10 integers to base 80 in Python without encountering IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I'm working on a Python script where I need to convert base 10 integers to base 80 using a specific set of characters. I've implemented a function for this purpose, but I keep encountering an IndexError due to the index going out of range. Here's the function I'm using:

```
def base10_to_base80(n):
    base_80 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_.~!$&\'()*+,:;=/'  # Corrected string
    if n == 0:
        return base_80[0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(base_80[n % 80])
        n //= 80
    return ''.join(digits[::-1])

# Example usage:
decimal_number = 79
base_80_number = base10_to_base80(decimal_number)
print(base_80_number)
```

Comment: Add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Your base_80 string does not have a length of 80

Comment: As an aside, the `divmod` function is useful here. `while n: n, r = divmod(n, 80); digest.append(base_80[r])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because

```
base_80 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_.~!$&\'()*+,:;=/
```

`len(base_80)` is `79`

you need one more character in `base_80` to make it work properly.

---

---

Your current code will work for base `79` you can just modify:

```
digits.append(base_80[n % 79])
        n //= 79
```

your code will work good.

Comment: Ahhh what a stupid mistake... . Thanks!